# IE onFocus not working when landing on page

Tags: javascript, input, onclick, onblur, onfocus

I have read a few threads on this using JS. Is there a way with or with using JS to get onFocus to work in IE when the user lands [on the page](http://dev.assessmentday.co.uk/aptitudetests_numerical.htm.)?

If you click on the search box and off again, the `search site...` appears. It works fine in all other browsers. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add value attribute to the search input field

```
<input value="search site..." class="searchBox" id="q" onfocus="this.value = this.value=='search site...'?'':this.value;" onblur="this.value = this.value==''?'search site...':this.value;" type="text" size="70"/>
```